# Validating Password

Tags: javascript, validation, passwords

I'm trying to validate a password using javascript, It's to make sure that when changing the password, the new password entered is equal to that of the re-entering of the new password (user is asked to enter their new password twice so both have to match) but at the same time, i want to make sure that the new password is at least 6 characters long, I have these functions separately but don't know how to combine them... thanks for help in advance!

This is what i have so far...

This is to make sure the new passwords match:

```
function validatePassword()
    {
     var new_password = document.getElementById("new_password").value;
     var confirm_new_password = document.getElementById("confirm_new_password").value;
     <!-- if they match, go to next page -->
        if ( new_password == confirm_new_password)
          {
             return true;
          }
     <!-- if they don't match, an error message is displayed -->
        else
          {
               alert("Passwords do not match.");
          }
             return false;
    }
```

This is for length of password:

```
 function validatePassword()
    {
    if (document.getElementById("new_password").value.length < "5")
    {
    <!--If pasword is less than 5 characters long, display error message-->
    alert("Please ensure your password is at least 6 characters long.");
    return false;
    }
    return true;
    }
```

How do i combine both of these to form a SINGLE function where the two new passwords are checked so that they match, and also check that they are longer than 6 characters?

Comment: FYI, Dropbox released their password validation js and it's by far the best I've seen - https://tech.dropbox.com/2012/04/zxcvbn-realistic-password-strength-estimation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To just combine your two functions, this would work:

```
function validatePassword()
{
     var new_password = document.getElementById("new_password").value;
     var confirm_new_password = document.getElementById("confirm_new_password").value;

     if (new_password.length < 5)
     {
         <!--If pasword is less than 5 characters long, display error message-->
         alert("Please ensure your password is at least 6 characters long.");
         return false;
     }
     else if ( new_password != confirm_new_password)
     {
         alert("Passwords do not match.");
         return false;
     }
     else
     {
          return true;
     }
 }
```

Although I agree, there are better procedures out there.  And please, make sure you're doing server-side validation as well since client-side validation is very easy to skip around.

Comment: Thanks for the help, this is for my school project so I'm very new to this, but thanks for the advice!

Comment: @user1930227 -- np, glad we could help. never too early to start learning best practices though.  best of luck.

Comment: There's a slight issue, it works fine though when a password longer than 6 characters is entered in, though the two passwords do not match, the update is still made. for example: if new_password = abcdefg (longer than 6) and confirm_password = abc (not the same), the password is updated

Comment: @user1930227 -- i updated the answer -- copied and pasted too fast (I assume you were still being prompted)...

Comment: aha thanks, i just fixed it myself (pretty proud of myself on that one) ahah, thanks for the help! :)

Comment: @user1930227 -- good job, now you're learning.  best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

i m not sure but you can call `validatePassword()` this function inside

```
if ( new_password == confirm_new_password)
{
    validatePassword();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options, either make the two functions a single function, or make them two separate functions and call them both before you submit / process your form.

```
if (validatePasswordLength() && validatePasswordsMatch()) {
    // Continue
}
```

Comment: I'd prefer to make the two functions into a single function, the second function is from another page that I have.

Answer (score 0):

you have to try this code that is small and working.

```
if(document.getElementById("new_password").value != document.getElementById("confirm_new_password").value){
     alert("Passwords do not match.");
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function validatePassword()
    {
     var new_password = document.getElementById("new_password").value;
     var confirm_new_password = document.getElementById("confirm_new_password").value;

    if (document.getElementById("new_password").value.length < "5")
    {
    alert("Please ensure your password is at least 6 characters long.");
    return false;
    }
     if (new_password == confirm_new_password)
     {
           alert("Password no match");
           return false;
     }
     return true;
    }
</script>
<form action="" onsubmit="return validatePassword()">
<p>New Password: <input type="password" id="new_password" name="new_password" /></p>
<p>Confirm Password: <input type="password" id="confirm_new_password" name="confirm_new_password" /></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="submit" /></p>
</form>
```